# Too many redirects on one website

Tags: magento-enterprise, multistore, enterprise-1.14, apache

Magento EE v1.14.x, CentOS 7

We already have a website/store/view shop which works fine, listening on 'shop.mydomain.co.uk'.

We just tried adding a new website/store/view by:

- Registering 'shop2.mydomain.co.uk' with DNS.
- Configuring Apache to serve virtualhost 'shop2.mydomain.co.uk':

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot /ssddata/www/shop.mydomain.co.uk
      ServerName shop2.mydomain.co.uk
      ErrorLog logs/shop2.mydomain.co.uk/error_log
      CustomLog logs/shop2.mydomain.co.uk/access_log common

      <Directory "/ssddata/www/shop.mydomain.co.uk">
          Require ip 10.11.0.0/16
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
      </Directory>

      SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "shop2_site_code"
      SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website"

  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Creating the appropriate new website/store/view in Magento Admin.
- Configuring Magento web management for the new site to use a new custom CMS homepage, new custom 'CMS No Route Page' and set the Base URL to use "http://shop2.mydomain.co.uk/".

Everything seems fine, and we have read at least a dozen online guides, however, when we browse to our new site ('shop2.mydomain.co.uk'), the browser responds with

```
shop2.mydomain.co.uk redirected you too many times.
```

I know there are many many similar questions everywhere on this issue, but none fit our circumstances (and none of their solutions work for us). For instance, the rest of our Magento instance is fine. The Admin area is still online and our primary shop is still working fine.

What I have done/checked:

- [magento root]/.htaccess is fine.
- All file permissions are fine.
- I have tried cleaning out all browser cookies, browsing "incognito" and even new browsers.
- Cleared out [magento root]/var/cache.
- Cleared out [magento root]/var/session.
- Flushed all Magento caches.
- Checked Apache and Magento logs.

I have found that if I remove the two **SetEnv** commands from the Apache virtualhost then I can browse to the 'shop2.mydomain.co.uk' URL but Magento serves the primary site/shop. So, it must be something to do with Magento trying to run the specified website code (via **MAGE_RUN_CODE**) which causes a loop. But I don't understand why or how.

We are running out of ideas as to why this new site is endlessly redirecting.

Does anyone have any suggestions to get this new site working please?

**UPDATE 1**
Something I should add is that when the browser reports "redirected you too many times", the address bar changes to: "http://shop2.mydomain.co.uk/no-route".
So Magento must be responding somehow, as it tries to redirect it to it's default "404 Page not found" page (URL-key: no-route). Interestingly though, the URL-key in our configuration for shop2.mydomain.co.uk's "404 page not found" page is actually "shop2-no-route", not "no-route". No idea if this is significant or helpful though! :)

Comment: is it correct that your DocumentRoot and Directory have different paths?

Comment: What are the Magento base URLs for your second shop?

Comment: @Robbie Averill, base URLs in Magento config for 'shop2.mydomain.co.uk' are: **Base URL: http://shop2.mydomain.co.uk/** (unsecure and secure). '**Use Secure URLs in Frontend**' is set to '**no**'.

Comment: @simonthesorcerer, typo on my behalf when typing up the question. Will fix :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I just nailed it!

- System > Configuration > [shop2.mydomain.co.uk Site Scope] > General

There's an option under section '**Website Restrictions**' for '**Landing Page**'. It was pointing to the default 404 CMS page (which explains my 'UPDATE1'). I changed that to point to our 'shop2.mydomain.co.uk' custom home page and we have something. There are some CSS issues but I think we can take it from here.

Thank you for all who have posted and read my query.

Cheers.